# Simplification of an expression using square roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am looking for some explanation and steps to show how the following expression was simplified to get the correct result.

$$\left|\left(r-3\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(r-3\frac{r-\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)\right|=|9-2r^2|$$

I have been trying to figure out how they simplified this but have been stuck on the process. Any solution would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$(r+\sqrt{r^2-4})(r-\sqrt{r^2-4})=4$$

and

$$(r+\sqrt{r^2-4})+(r-\sqrt{r^2-4})=2r$$

**SPOLIER ALERT:  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.**

> Note that we have $$\begin{align}\left(r-3\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(r-3\frac{r-\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)&=r^2\\\\&-\frac32 r\left((r+\sqrt{r^2-4})+(r-\sqrt{r^2-4})\right)\\\\&+\frac94(r+\sqrt{r^2-4})(r-\sqrt{r^2-4})\\\\&=r^2-\frac32r(2r)+\frac94(4)\\\\&=9-2 r^2\end{align}$$

Comment: @jh123 How does it not help?

Comment: Would the foil method  work in this situation?

Comment: @jh123 Yes, it does.  I've edited to add the solution in the highlighted area.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for your submition! but in the last two steps shouldn't the answer be $9-2r^2?$ since $r^2-\frac{3}{2}r(2r)+\frac{4}{9}(4)=r^2-3r^2+9?$

Comment: Indeed.  I've edited the typo.

Comment: @Dr.MV okay thanks, looks like everything else is good

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV in your hint you use a + and a - sign then in your answer in step 2 you use + and a +, was this supposed to be a + and a - like your hint?

Comment: You're correct.  Cutting and pasting can be hazardous.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks a lot for your help, typing the proper formatting for this kind of question can be a little tedious, Thanks for your time!

Comment: And thank you for catching the typos.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is:

Take $3$s out of brackets:
$9\left(\frac{r}{3}-\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{r}{3}-\frac{r-\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)$

Now consider the quadratic factorization: $x^2-rx+1=\left(x-\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{r-\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}\right)$.

Multiplying both sides by $9$ and plugging $x=\frac{r}{3}$ will do.